# How to find slopes of multiple regression?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I'm making a plot of several linear regressions and I would like to find the slope of each of them. The problem is that I don't find how to do it in my case.
Like you can see on my plot, I'm testing the weight as a function of the temperature, a quality (my two colors) and quantity (my facet wrap).

[image]

My code for this plot is that :

```
g = ggplot(donnees_tot, aes(x=temperature, y=weight, col = quality))+
     geom_point(aes(col=quality), size = 3)+
     geom_smooth(method="lm", span = 0.8,aes(col=quality, fill=quality))+
     scale_color_manual(values=c("S" = "aquamarine3",
                              "Y" = "darkgoldenrod3"))+
     scale_fill_manual(values=c("S" = "aquamarine3",
                             "Y" = "darkgoldenrod3"))+
     scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(20,25,28), limits=c(20,28))+
     annotate("text", x= Inf, y = - Inf, label =eqn, parse = T, hjust=1.1, vjust=-.5)+
     facet_wrap(~quantity)
   g
```

Also, if you have a tips to write them on my plot, I would be really grateful !
Thank you

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/7549694/17144974

Comment: you should look at the [ggpmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpmisc/vignettes/model-based-annotations.html) package

Comment: Thank you, I've watched the topic of this link and with the ggpmisc package, I solved my problem

Comment: You can calculate the slope yourself: e.g.,  `df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = c(0, 2, rnorm(6), 7, 9)
)

lm(df$y ~ df$x)$coeff[2]
     df$x 
0.6469238 `

Answer (score 0):

By using the ggpmisc package, I've had these lines to my code and it works !

```
stat_poly_line() +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label),
                                 after_stat(rr.label), sep = "*\", \"*"))) +
```